# SonarQube resetting quality profile every week to default

Tags: sonarqube

We're analyzing our code with SonarQube 6.1 and started to encounter this issue since version 6.

The code is a Maven 3 project, built with Jenkins, using the [SonarQube Maven Scanner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven).

- We have a quality profile *Q* that inherits from the default profile *P*.
- The code is being analyzed daily.
- On every Friday, the quality profile of the project is somehow reset to the default profile *P*. On Saturday, it is properly set to *Q* again.

The change of quality profiles can be seen in the project history. Also, the changed quality profile is noted in the log of Jenkins.

What I analyzed:

- Logs: There is no POST request to the sonar "qualityprofiles" API noted in the access log.
- There are no cronjobs running to my knowledge.
- There are no Jobs on Jenkins setting the 'sonar.profile' variable
- The analyzed profile also does not set 'sonar.profile'
- The scanner context of the runs only differ in the setting 'sonar.cpd.cross_project': Enabled in the 'wrong' run - disabled in the 'proper' run

Comment: is there a different job executed on that day? is there a weekly job you could have missed?
Is there anything in the SonarQube Scanner logs?

Comment: @Teryk-SonarSourceTeam: We searched for POST request to the "qualityprofile" API in the access logs - nothing.
The jobs look okay to us - but we're happy for any pointers to find a misbehaving one... AFAIK we don't change profiles in any job or via the API, only in the project configuration.

Comment: don't you have a job or someone applying permission template on a list of project?

Comment: There is no permission template matching that project - we barely use this feature. Also, I couldn't find any occurrence of the API in the logs.
May I suggest we continue this in chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131230/sonarqube

Comment: Are you sure that on friday the job that is doing the analysis is not adding the -Dsonar.profile=P to scanner ?

Comment: Affirmative - it is the same Jenkins-Job every day.
The Maven call we can observe is (shortened) `mvn -B -f [...]/pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/home/jenkins/ci/maven-repositories/0 -s [...]/settings.xml --update-snapshots --toolchains [...] --activate-profiles [...] -Dsonar.host.url=[...] -Dsonar.login=[...] clean install sonar:sonar`
I also checked the "Scanner context", and grep'ed through all the config.xml in our Jenkins - there is no 'sonar.profile' entry.
One aspect I may have forgot to mention: The project has explicitly disabled cross-project detection. Our default is enabled.